# Creating unique ID for overlapping polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing, overlapping-features, union

In QGIS I created a union from a layer that had a lot of overlapping polygons. In the union layer, I used the Field Calculator (see the formula I used below) to count how many overlaps there were, as you can see if the photo.

```
count("id", group_by:=geom_to_wkt($geometry))
```

When I use "identify features" tool, it shows all the rows that are in that union. In the photo example, it has 6 rows from the attribute table. When opening the attribute table, there is no way I can see which 6 rows are grouped together.

Is there a way to see this other than using the "identity features" tool? I would like to add a unique id for these groups.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try the selection tool? Overlapping polygons can be distinguished in the attribute table after selection.